# Retrieving response with cookie with curl

Tags: php

I am trying to check if a cookie exists on a server with a specific url.

```
    $ch=curl_init();
//curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "mm=38533;" );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'/tmp/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.engageya.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$response=curl_exec($ch);
// get cookie
preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $response, $m);

curl_close($ch);

var_dump(parse_url($m[1]));
echo "<br/>".$response;
```

The problem is when I am logged in onto the target site, and I need to check if I am logged into the site, so I try to retrieve the cookie from the site..But i fail.
I thought to use the curlopt_cookie option..but I thought if there is an easy way to return the cookie from the server and check if it exists .

In short the cookie exists when I surf to the page. But it doesnt exist when the request comes back and i print it

Comment: Cookies don't live on the server. They live on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the target host isn't available. Maybe a typo in url or it is really not available. I added the following option to curl:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
```

Now I can see the following error:

```
* getaddrinfo(3) failed for www.engagya.com:80
* Couldn't resolve host 'www.engagya.com'
```

---

Update: After fixing the typo in the url, I got the following example working:

```
<?php

$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.engageya.com/wordpress/api/?action=isloggedin&uid=22472');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$response=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// use preg_match to get the cookie as in your question:
preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*);/mi', $response, $m);
var_dump($m);
```

Comment: Ok, we'll see. step by step. :)

Comment: problem is the headers dont help, because the cookie is set once.. i need to see if the cookie exists on the server. it gets a cookie being set each time. But i dont want to get a response that a cookie is set. I want to check for pre-existing cookies..check perhaps the cookie on the server, if it is saved there.

Comment: What do you mean with: 'The cookie exists on the server'.. ?

Comment: when you do set_cookie.. where is the cookie saved? on the server , right? how do I retrieve it? when i am on that page , the cookie does exist..which means it is saved on the server.. i think the problem is with this...curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'/tmp/cookies.txt');.. i need to find where the cookie is on the server..am I right?

Comment: :) A cookie is in any case saved on the **client**. I think what you mean is a session that is saved on server and identified by a cookie